# When does it make sense to handle a SIGSEGV signal?

Tags: segmentation-fault

Searching here and there I found some supposedly valid cases, but none of them gave a good (or any) explanation as to why this was the best (or only) choice.

Here are the cases:

1. Try to perform some kind of clean-up before crashing.
2. Provide a friendly error report to the user and maybe send an error report back to you.
3. Use it for debugging.
4. Try to perform a full recovery of your program.

Here are my thought on the cases:

1. SIGSEGV signals should not be there in the first place, but then again there is Murphy's law and there are some resources that an OS won't release implicitly after a program crashes (I am thinking about semaphores or shared memory).
2. Again, there is Murphy's law. Displaying a dialog when things go wrong and asking permission from the user to send an automated report seems very good for both the user and the developer. (I don't remember if any of the error reports of the programs that I use ever mentioned a segmentation fault, though. I guess I will start noticing now.)
3. I have never ever even thought of this option. A debugger and a core dump look like a much more effective approach.
4. For all I know, this is either impossible or illogical, since the program state is corrupted, making the execution unpredictable (this is another good argument against (1), (2) and (3)). I don't know if there is a very specific case where that might actually make sense, though. This reminds me of an argument in favor of turning assertions off in production software: that sometimes erroneous execution is better than no execution, sometimes being aviation software and the like.

So:

- Are there any good reasons to handle a SIGSEGV signal?
- Are any of the above cases indeed valid? Why or why not?
- Why are we allowed to handle SIGSEGV in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You have a program that's supposed to run 24/7 processing stuff (e.g. handling messages) all the time and it uses a third party component to do some of the processing. This third party component sometimes fails with a SIGSEGV.

Clearly, the best long-term solution is to get the vendor to fix the component or use another component, but the short-term solution is to log the error and keep going.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "keep going"? What do you execute after the signal handler?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm mostly working with event-based programming, so at the lower level, I just mean the windows event loop or equivalent keeps going.

Comment: This seems to fall into case #4. Interesting. It would be great if you could expand your answer and cover all the points in my question.

Comment: Yeah, a true `SIGSEGV` will be in a *NIX environment, and I've not programmed for that for over 15 years. My answer was referring to a general case I know about. Your "thoughts" in your question effectively answer the other cases. Of course, an average `SIGSEGV` _does_ mean "the program state is corrupted, making the execution unpredictable" and you can't do much than try to log the error and allow the program to terminate. My scenario is only available when the underlying bug does not randomly corrupt state before causing the signal.